# Code not assessing peaks correctly

Tags: c, while-loop

i have a code that prints out the number of peaks and their given magnitudes. the input is in the form of a single line that contains random integers separated by white space. a peak is only defined to be so when it is **directly preceded and followed** by a smaller value.
examples:

```
0 4 18 18 26 40 40 29 25 2 0         //has one peak of magnitude 40.
20 10 20         /*has no peaks, because both 20's are either not 
                   preceded or followed by a smaller number.*/
```

the code fails to behave correctly when the input data, `c`, begins with a declining set of numbers. 
for example, the input: `9 8 7 6 5 4` returns a peak of "9", when it shouldn't return any magnitude. 
another situation where it's behaving incorrectly is when we have the following input: `10 10 10 5 5 5 12 12 12 -1`. its returning a magnitude of "10", while again, it shouldn't return any magnitude because it doesn't fulfill the conditions of a peak .

the following is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("Number  Magnitude\n");


    while (c >= 0){

        if ((b > a) && (b > c)) {     //to check if we have a peak     
            counter++;
            printf("%4d%11d\n", counter, b);
            a = b;
            b = c;
            scanf("%d", &c);

        }

        else if ((a < b) && (b == c)) {
            b = c;
            scanf("%d", &c);
        }   
        else {
            a = b;
            b = c;
            scanf("%d", &c);
        }       
    }

}
```

i prefer to keep the level of coding as minimum as possible, as i haven't done more than loops and if statements at this stage.

Comment: couldn't you write single `scanf()` after all the `if else` block??

Comment: for your 4th example `10 10 10 5 5 5 12 12 12 -1` if the last element is positive number smaller than `12` say `5` shouldn't the peak be `12`?

Comment: It can be easily done using an array but first i have to understand the problem description clearly..

Comment: @AsifRahaman yes, that could be possible for ur first question. yes again for ur second question, as the repeated numbers in a row would be treated as a single integer. and in that case, if it was preceded and followed by a smaller integer, it would be considered as a peak.

Comment: @AsifRahaman , also, i prefer to not use arrays as i haven't learned them yet. unless u cannot help me without the use of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is being caused because you initialize your boundary values to the minimum possible value.  Any possible peak value will test positive when compared to that boundary value.

A small change fixes it, both boundary values should be set to a value that tests negative when compared to any possible peak value:

```
int a = INT_MAX;
int b = INT_MAX;
```

You will however to detect new lines and reset your values if you want to be able to do multiple lines of input, but I believe this is an existing problem

Comment: Thank you. that simple trick solved it all. it works just fine as the input will always be a single line. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you should try to ask the program to mimic what you would to by hand: you must considere 3 value, so you must read 3 values before testing for a peak. And you should always control the return value from `scanf` to be able to process and end of file or an incorrect input.

Your code could become:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int cr;

    cr = scanf("%d%d%d", &a,&b,&c);
    if (cr != 3) {
        printf("Incorrect input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Number  Magnitude\n");


    while ((cr > 0) && (c >= 0)) {

        if ((b > a) && (b > c)) {     //to check if we have a peak     
            counter++;
            printf("%4d%11d\n", counter, b);
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }

        else if ((a >= b) || (b != c)) {
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }   // nothing to do if a<b and b==c
        cr = scanf("%d", &c); // read once outside of the loop
    }
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, above code allows multi-line input.